# Getting full path from an HTTP request

Tags: java, path, httprequest

I would like to know how can I get the full path of an HTTP request.

If a have a request like `http://localhost:8080/path1/path2` how can I get the full `/path1/path2`?

Using `request.getContextPath()` returns only the /path1 section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [the `getRequestURI()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29):

The documentation describes it thus:

> Returns the part of this request's URL from the protocol name up to the query string in the first line of the HTTP request.

Comment: I've always wondered about the wording here: "..from the protocol name up to...", yet the protocol and host/port is not returned by this method?! Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following.

```
request.getRequestURI()
```

you get

> /path1/path2

as the result.
You got my point? or any query?

Comment: it will return /path1/path2. Note the leading '/'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could extract the HOST header from the request like in this example:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html

You can then concatenate it with your context path. The only thing I'm not sure is if it includes https:// in case it runs over SSL, but there should be a way to find out or maybe know it if you always use the same protocol...

Regards